# Tao overriding parent reset.css file. 

Tags: 6, theming

I wish to override one of the default css files provided from the theme I am inheriting from. According to [Creating a sub-theme](http://drupal.org/node/225125) page I need to do the following:

> **Overriding inherited style sheets:** Specify a style sheet with the same
>   filename in the sub-theme. For instance, to override style.css
>   inherited from a parent theme, add the following line to your
>   sub-theme's .info file:
>
> `stylesheets[all][]   = style.css`
>
> You will also need to create the style.css stylesheet file; if you
>   simply wish to disable the imported styles, you can create an empty
>   file.

My parent theme (Tao) has a reset.css file. In mytheme I have added the following to mytheme.info

```
stylesheets[all][]   = reset.css
```

I have then create a blank file called `reset.css` and it is in the root of my theme. I have run `drush cc all` but the parent css file is still being read.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tao inclueds reset for print and for screen so you should override like so.

```
stylesheets[print][]   = reset.css
stylesheets[screen][]   = reset.css
```

Using the `all` array will only override other items in the `all` array not both `screen` and `print`